how to make app for samsung's edge panel?

So I wanted to make an calculator app using samsumg's edge panel feature. is there any samsung api to make our own custom edge panel like showed in this picture ?
I tried searching for SDK to achieve it but I couldn't find anywhere. If you find an hello world program in github. please comment.
